# Make comments on articles

Tags: php, mongodb

i want make comments on article but i have errors can you correct my mistakes :

- i'm not sur for the line :    `$_SESSION['user_id'] = '';`
- and i have errors for this line

  $database->insert->comments($comment);
       return $comment['_id'];

Errors are :

> - Undefined variable: database in
> - Trying to get property of non-object in
> - Call to a member function comments() on a non-object in

thanks you

My file photo.php

```
<?php
try {
           $connection = new MongoClient();
           $database   = $connection->selectDB('test');
           $collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
         } Catch(MongoException $e) {
           die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}
         $cursor = $collection->find();
       ?>

<?php session_start(['user_id']); 
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = '';
?>

<article class="photo">
  <img src="french.jpg">

  <section class="comments">
    <article class="comment">
      <header>Jean-Raphael</header>
      Wouah cool
    </article>
    <article class="comment">
      <header>Gaëlle</header>
   JR lol
    </article>

    <form class="comment" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="photo_comment" value="true" />
      <textarea name="comment">
      </textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="comment"/>
    </form>
  </section>
</article>

<?php

function process_comment_if_any_comment_posted ()
{
   $comment = get_posted_comment_if_any_and_secure();
   if(invalid_or_no_comment($comment)) return;
   insert_comment($comment);
}

process_comment_if_any_comment_posted();

function get_posted_comment_if_any_and_secure()
{
  $comment = array();

  if(! comment_posted()) return $comment;

  $text = check_and_secure($_POST, 'comment');
  if($text == "") return $comment;

  $comment['text'] = $text;
  $comment['author'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];


  global $photo;

  $comment['photo'] = $photo['_id'];

  return $comment;
}

function invalid_or_no_comment($comment)
{
  return empty($comment)
    || ! isSet($comment['text'])
    || (trim($comment['text']) == "");
}

function insert_comment($comment)
{
  $database->insert->comments($comment);
  return $comment['_id'];
}

function get_photo()
{
  $photo = array();


  return $photo;
}

$photo = get_photo();

function comment_posted()
{
   return isSet($_POST['photo_comment']);
}

function check_and_secure($T, $field)
{
  if(! isSet($T[$field])) return "";
  return htmlentities($T[$field]);
}
```

Comment: Far as I know, `session_start()` doesn't take a parameter. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php `bool session_start ( void )`

Comment: It's not a "put that where", it's to change `session_start(['user_id']);` to `session_start();` and if you want to set the session array to anything, it's something like `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $var;` - `$var` being an example or as you have it now. You'll need to figure that out.

Comment: now  Undefined variable: var

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting indicates that *$database* is undefined, which you define at the top of the file in the try-catch block but you have to bring it into local scope of your insert_comment() function:

```
function insert_comment($comment)
{
  global $database;
  $database->insert->comments($comment);
  return $comment['_id'];
}
```

Also, as Fred in the comments pointed out, session_start() doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: now i have this Call to undefined method MongoCollection::comments()

Comment: @AnisMrad that is an error occurring somewhere else from the code snippet you gave us.

Comment: but i have just this file

Comment: @AnisMrad In the MongoCollection class, the comments() method isn't defined. I jumped to conclusions a bit quickly in my previous comment, but you are calling an undefined method in your insert_comment() function.